# Why is the interface lost when using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I came across something today that I found surprising and was hoping someone could explain to me what is happening. It appears that Linq enumerables can interfere with the interfaces implemented by objects. If you run this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    interface One
    {
        int id {get; set; }
    }

    class A : One
    {
        public int id {get; set; }
    }

    interface Two
    {
    }

    class B : A, Two
    {
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<One>() { new B {id = 1} };

        var b1 = list.Where(x => x.id == 1);
        var b2 = list.First();

        Console.WriteLine(b1 is Two);
        Console.WriteLine(b2 is Two);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
False
True
```

I was expecting the same object to be returned by Where() and First(), but apparently the objects returned have different types. Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks!
-Tom B.

Comment: `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<One>`

Comment: Where returns an `IEnumerable<T>` because multiple results could satisfy the condition.

Comment: var b1 = list.Single(x => x.id == 1); //console should print true

Comment: In Visual Studio, if you're unclear on what type a `var` actually is, hover over it. `var` is neat and all, but not if it means you don't know what you're doing anymore.

Comment: The answers are already good and cover it pretty well so I will not add another answer, but to add an analogy: what you are doing is similar to `list is Two` vs `list[0] is Two`. The `List<One>` does not implement `Two` but the first item in `List<One>` does. Linq is doing the same thing but you are working with `IEnumerable<One>` instead of a `List<One>`.

Comment: Once again: the value of a LINQ query is *a query*, not *the results of a query*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Where()` will return an `IEnumerable<One>`, rather than a single object of `One` since the condition could be met by multiple `One` objects within the `List<One>`. The `.First()` method will retrieve the first `One` object that can be found in the `IEnumerable<One>`.